# Web scraping using rvest: indistinguishable CSS selectors prevent me from scraping certain blocks

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am using SelectorGadget tool to identify CSS selectors for some rvest code that is supposed to extract property amenities, room amenities and room types from a page at TripAdvisor. The following code scrapes both highlighted and unhighlighted property amenities. Unfortunately, I cannot do the same thing for room amenities and room types.

```
library(rvest)
hotel_url="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187791-d13494726-Reviews-Palazzo_Caruso-Rome_Lazio.html"
hotel<-hotel_url%>%read_html()
property_amenities<-hotel%>%
    html_node(".hotels-hr-about-amenities-AmenityGroup__amenitiesList--3MdFn")%>%
    html_children()
property_amenities_highlighted<-amenities[1:(length(amenities)-1)] %>% html_text()
property_amenities_unhighlighted<-amenities[length(amenities)] %>% html_children() %>% html_text()
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a separate CSS selector responsible for room features and room types.
How can we extract room features and room types either to separate lists or to the same list as property_amenities (as they will be binary-coded later anyway).

Comment: Have you tried multi-level css selectors to find a unique set? Example: `html_node("div.listing > div.detail > span:nth-of-type(2)". I'm not checking TripAdvisor because I'm not sure if they allow scraping.

Comment: If you do not mind to scrape all you could do the following. `read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187791-d13494726-Reviews-Palazzo_Caruso-Rome_Lazio.html") %>% html_nodes("div.hotels-hr-about-amenities-Amenity__amenity--3fbBj") %>% html_text()`. I also think that TripAdvisor does not allow scraping.

Comment: TripAdvisor was used just as an example. Thank you for showing me the power of html_nodes function. It worked out perfectly!